# Simple exclusion script for journey builder send

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, suppressionlist, exclusion-script

I have an existing journey in journey builder. The emails it sends now have to exclude people present on another data extension. Having never used exclusion scripts before, what would I need to write to exclude subscribers who appear in another DE?

Comment: How is your journey triggered? By API or through automation?

Comment: This one is triggered by an automation which runs hourly, filtering another DE and firing every few minutes.

Comment: You should use a query activity, then, to select who you inject into the interaction. Excision scripts are great, but not for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exclusion script is simply simply with certain conditions). Take for example, you want to exclude certain subscribers from a send, you can simply use this:

```
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("ExclusionDE", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) > 0)
```

This assumes that you are currently compiling the subscribers you want to exlude in the `ExclusionDE`. The script just check against email address to see if they are present. If they are, they will not be sent the email.

Comment: Thanks that looks good but shouldn't it be greater than or equal to rather than just greater than?

Comment: Ah!!! good catch will update!

Comment: > 0 works just as well :)

Comment: There are some cases `where > 1` is correct -- like when you're checking rows from a triggered send data extension.  those rows are written before the AMPScript is evaluated.